# Laravel: How to import external library in a controller class

Tags: php, laravel, dom

Hello all I am trying to add an external library in my laravel project more specifically i did this steps
first i run the

```
composer require "ivopetkov/html5-dom-document-php:2.*"
```

and the output i got is this

```
composer require "ivopetkov/html5-dom-document-php:2.*"
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update ivopetkov/html5-dom-document-php
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Lock file operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Locking ivopetkov/html5-dom-document-php (v2.2.9)
Writing lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Downloading ivopetkov/html5-dom-document-php (v2.2.9)
  - Installing ivopetkov/html5-dom-document-php (v2.2.9): Extracting archive
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
Discovered Package: facade/ignition
Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
Discovered Package: fruitcake/laravel-cors
Discovered Package: laravel/sail
Discovered Package: laravel/socialite
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Discovered Package: nesbot/carbon
Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collision
Package manifest generated successfully.
74 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
```

After that i check the composer.json file that everything is setup correctly

```
  "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "ivopetkov/html5-dom-document-php": "2.*",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.12",
        "laravel/socialite": "^5.1",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5"
    },
```

so the library

```
"ivopetkov/html5-dom-document-php": "2.*",
```

is loaded correct now my probelm is how to import it in my class controller

perhaps something like this

```
use Laravel\ivopetkov\html5-dom-document-php;
```

Can y help me find the appropriate way to import the library correctly?

Comment: Looking at their [github](https://github.com/ivopetkov/html5-dom-document-php) page you need to `use IvoPetkov\HTML5DOMDocument;` and then `$dom = new HTML5DOMDocument();`

Comment: @RJK i am getting error when i $dom = new IvoPetkov\HTML5DOMDocument(); any fixes?

Comment: Sorry, I updated my comment with the required changes

Comment: i am still gettting error when i also  $dom = new HTML5DOMDocument();

Comment: Please see this [sandbox](https://phpsandbox.io/n/delicate-limit-bpkv-n9imp) of a working example

Comment: ok its working thnxx you can answer the question and i will mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have posted a [sandbox](https://phpsandbox.io/n/delicate-limit-bpkv-n9imp) of a working example if you want to play around with it.

But once you have installed the composer package you can "import" the package by adding the following to the top of the script:

`use IvoPetkov\HTML5DOMDocument;`

Then you can use the package, this example was taken from their [github](https://github.com/ivopetkov/html5-dom-document-php) page:

```
$dom = new HTML5DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>Hello</body></html>');
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```